# Offset Composable by percentage in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I simply want to offset an Image always the exact amount no matter what screen resolution the user has.

I tried it like this:

```
var heightIs by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .aspectRatio(
                ratio = 1f
            ).onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                heightIs = (coordinates.size.height.toFloat())
            }
    ) {

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.base),
            contentDescription = "Shadow",
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.top_mask_normal),
            contentDescription = "Shadow Stencil",
            colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(color, BlendMode.SrcAtop),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .offset(y = ((heightIs * 0.03).toInt()).dp)
        )
}
```

But I get different results on different screen resolutions.
I want it **exactly** at the same position every time not matter if the user uses a tablet or a 480x800 device

Comment: You want the offset to denote the same distance for every screen resolution, but you're calculating the offset based on the screen height? What exactly do you think you're doing here, sir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this line, `heightIs * 0.03).toInt()).dp`, you are not converting to dp or density independent pixels. You are adding .dp extension to end of pixel value.

To convert to dp you need to use `LocalDensity.current.run{heightIs * 0.03).toInt().toDp()}`

dp is calculated as pixels / density. If your device has 2.0 density 100px should be 50.dp but with your existing function you simply change `100px` to `100.dp`

Comment: Dr. Thrace, the question is paradoxical. The OP needs the exact distance (like in centimeters) to be the same for all the devices the app runs on, but is still calculating it using the device's specific height. He wants to jump off a space station without a parachute and still wants to survive. Your answer is helpful though,

Comment: Also, OP, consider upvoting the answer alongside marking it as correct. It is a sign of gratitude and is expected conventionally of askers when their issues are resolved.

Comment: @RichardOnslowRoper i don't think it's paradoxical. OP wants to have position of a Composable being in same percent across all devices. This is an approach i also use with Canvas to have lines or shapes respective to screen width or height to have similar look in any View or Composable size like in this compass in [this link](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compass-with-pixel-perfect). Only thing OP missed out was converting to dp which can be confusing. I remember another similar question trying to convert to dp by adding `dp` to end of pixel value

Comment: My point was he never mentioned *percent*. In fact, he mentioned "the exact **amount**", and "I want it **exactly** at the same **position** every time not matter if the user uses a tablet or a 480x800 device". Those are clearly conflicting with the fact that the offset is dependent on height. how could you have 20% height of a 400x800px device the same as the 20% of a 400x1000px? Mathematically illogical and senseless.

Comment: [THAT](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compass-with-pixel-perfect) is SOME compass man!

Comment: @RichardOnslowRoper Thanks for the compliment about Compose. I will rewrite it with Compose when i'm available. Using percentages is way better than dp values especially with Canvas. You can scale based on any reference dimension from 100.dp to 1000.dp yet get the same results since everything is drawn relative to initial radius or each other

Comment: Actually you know what, I have a billion dollar idea, but I'm struggling with designing the UI. It is something similar to a compass design, though not exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with `heightIs` is that it will cause recomposition when it is updated in onGloballyPositioned.

Compose provides the [layout](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/custom#layout-modifier) modifier to resolve that problem.

Something like that would work, without having to use a state

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .aspectRatio(
            ratio = 1f
        )
) {

    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.base),
        contentDescription = "Shadow",
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.top_mask_normal),
        contentDescription = "Shadow Stencil",
        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(color, BlendMode.SrcAtop),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .layout { measurable, constraint ->
                val placeable = measurable.measure(constraint)

                layout(constraint.width, constraint.height) {
                    placeable.placeRelative(
                        x = 0, 
                        y = (constraint.height * 0.03).toInt()
                    )
                }
            }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.dp` just returns a `Dp` type object. You want to ensure the Composable moves by a fixed 'distance', no matter the density of the screen, but pixels are of variable sizes. You'll need some sort of conversion mechanism that converts your pixel value to the something that equals the same distance on their device as it did on your device with a different density. Hence, you need the set the value (in pixels, say) on your device based on your preferred distance; then you need to convert that value **on your device** to a `Dp` value. Then, the value you get from the conversion can be used everywhere else, on any device and it will return the same 'length', in principle.

Let's say you want a `Dp`, that is, Density-Independent Pixel value for 500 pixels on your device. The conversion process is

```kotlin
{ // ComposableScope
  val dips = with(LocalDensity.current) { pixels.toDp() }
}
```

Now, this value is just to get the converted pixel value to DPs. Log this value, or get it through the debugger or print it on screen or use whicvever method you want to retrieve this value. Once the value is in your hands, you no longer need this code. Just initialise the `dips` variable with the retrieved value and it will work well on every device (in principle).

Also take a took at [Doctor Thracian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73740939/15880865).